# How to exclude employees with special character in their email in Eloquent

Tags: laravel

In Larevel 5.8, I have this query.

There is also a field called employee_number. Some of the employees have their employee numbers as:

retired-110, retired-221, retired-132 ... and so on.

The numbers 110, 221, etc , can go on and on. What is constant is retired. It shouldn't select those that have retired in their employee_number

How do I exclude all the employees that have retired in their employee_number from this query:

```
$employees = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_status', 0)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please trie this example

```
$employees = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_status', 0)->where('employee_number', 'NOT LIKE', 'retired%')->get();
```

Comment: I think you don't have to put `%` before retired (it still works). It will not use `index` in that way if any. but `retired%` will use.